# MySQLの日付とテーブルにはいっているcreatedの日付の差分をとりたい

Tags: mysql, sql

A
 `SELECT CURDATE();`

+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2016-01-26 |
+------------+

B

`SELECT created FROM products;`

+---------------------+
| created             |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-11 11:12:53 |
+---------------------+

上記のAとBの月の差分をとって、5と出したいのですが、

`SELECT`内で１つにまとめて算出させたのですが、どのような記述になりますか？

Comment: MySQLのバージョンはいくつでしょう？

Comment: バージョンはMySQL5.6です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL の [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) を利用します。

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, created, CURDATE()) AS diff, created
FROM products;
```